# How to Choose Which Field a Foreign Key References in LoopbackJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, mysql-connector, relationships

I would like to know how to choose a field which a foreign key references. I can't find it in the docs.

For example, if I have a `Product` table and a `ProductTag` table. A `Product` **hasMany** `ProductTags`. Then my `ProductTag` table will have a foreign key to the `Product` table via:

```
{ // Product
  ...
  "relations": {
    "productTags": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ProductTag",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
}
```

The fields of my `Product` table are `id` - *i want to set this as id*, `sku` - *unique*, `price`, etc...

Then the relationship will create a foreign key referencing `Product.id`. How do I reference it to `Product.sku` instead?

Thank you!

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasMany-relations.html#defining-a-hasmany-relation

I fail to see how `foreignKey` and `primaryKey` don't do exactly what you want

Comment: Woah! I missed that one. Thank you very much! :) Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Please also note that the description of `primaryKey` is here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/BelongsTo-relations.html#overview. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasMany-relations.html#defining-a-hasmany-relation)

```
  "relations": {
    "orders": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Order",
      "foreignKey": "customerId",
      "primaryKey": "id" // optional
    },
```

> The target model, Order, has a property, **customerId, as the foreign
>   key** to reference the declaring model (Customer) **primary key id**.

Answer (score 0):

Your product has many product tags so in your Product table you have hasMany relation but in ProductTagTable you have belongsTo relation because productTag belongs to ProductTable.

For better options,
You can use **lb model** command will ask you that how you want to make a relationship and which name do you want for foreignKey.

Thank you.